# "I've been decided"

Tags: grammar, sentence, lyrics

Is it grammatically correct to say "I've been decided"?

The idea is that I want to stress that I have not decided to do something; instead, it has been decided without me that I would do this.

If this is incorrect, what is the closest analog?

P.S.: I am going to use this in a song lyrics, not in everyday speech.

Comment: It's used, to imply that the decision has been effectively made for you by circumstances.  Not "formal", but certainly OK in a lyric.

Comment: Wouldn't "It's been decided" be a better fit?

Comment: If someone tells me that "You have been decided, I shall quickly inform the police." ;) :)

Answer (score 4):

"I've been volunteered" is in common usage and also plays off the same theme that you're being forced into doing something, whilst outwardly appearing to have decided to do it yourself.

Comment: Yes, and an informal version of this (which doesn't exist as a commonly accepted word) is *voluntold*, which makes it clear that *you* didn't volunteer, but somebody else did it on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

If "I" is intended as the object of "decide", neither the Oxford nor the Cambridge online dictionaries give examples that fit your construction. I can decide something but I cannot be decided, essentially because I am not a decision - that just does not make sense, not even in the sentence "My parents decided on me" (= they decided to have a baby), which is the closest I can get to making myself the object of "decide".

The other meaning is acceptable, if you say something like "I have been decided for some time that I should write a lyric". In this case "decided" describes your state of being.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> The idea is that I want to stress that I have not decided to do something; instead, it has been decided without me that I would do this.

It should be the passive form "It has been decided [by someone] that I will do X."

> Is it grammatically correct to say "I've been decided"?

No, not in that context.

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem in using this construction, it is quite current ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=15&year_end=2008&content=decide+him&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdecide%20him%3B%2Cc0) and the meaning of the verb "to decide" in this transitive use is verified in the Shorter OED.

- **2** *v.t* Bring (a person) to a determination or resolution (*against, in favour, to do*) Early 18th century.

"To have been decided" means that one has *accepted* to do something but it does not mean that they did it willingly.

Comment: Are the usage guides (against, in favour, to do) caveats that some complement is necessary? 'Put [something] [_down, on, under_ ...]' doesn't mean that 'John put the jug.' is grammatical. But more importantly, the meaning here is not what OP requires: 'It has been decided _for_ me (my decision would still be to refuse)'. The above is 'It has brought / caused me to decide'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "(Against, in favour, to do)" are guides for *possible* relevant addition: For instance, "I have been decided against my will to go to this school.". I have been decided (by someone)" is passive; it means that this corresponds to the active "someone decided me" the object "me" becoming the subject "I" as in all such correpondences: someone told me/I have been told (by someone). Indeed this is not a case of "it has been decided for me".

Comment: You have a reference licensing 'I have been decided against my will to go to this school'? And the S-OED definition here is of the form 'These events decided me (= virtually forced me to take the decision) to renounce my views on Communism', not 'My parents decided me (= made the decision for me) to go to Eton, though I've always been determined to go to St Trinian's, which I will do next year.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I do not see a difference between "events decided me" and  "parents decided me" as long as a complement does not figure so as to make a difference clear; in both cases it is basically "bring to a determination" bring to the acceptation, either through force or through reasoned convincing. In "decided for me" the opinion of the person for whom the decision is made is not  of any consequence or  is assumed; this is so in particular in the context of tutelage.

Comment: 'Events decided me to ...' means I made a (heavily) informed decision to .... // OP asks << Is it grammatically correct to say "I've been decided"?

The idea is that I want to stress that I have _not_ decided to do something >> Compare  JeffUK's "I've been volunteered!" meaning _I didn't volunteer at all: what was supposed to be a voluntary task has been (wrongly) forced by those in power upon me._ I had **no** choice, not I chose reluctantly.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see, it sounds like coercion, illegal practices,  possibly usurpation of personal prerogatives; nevertheless, there has been the acceptance of what has been decided, even if as the result of coercion;( btw, if what has been accepted is illegal the courts of law will take into account the coercion but anyway they'll acknowledge an **unlawfull decision**, a case of culpability.) I still believe that this transitive verb is proper except that given the particular situation you highlight and that I didn't pay enough attention to, a complement is needed (e.g. "through coercion").

Comment: I'd say it's a non-standard usage ("I've been decided" = "I had no say in the matter, wasn't even consulted"; rather like the more acceptable wry "I've been volunteered").